# Pick out an element from a row in a SQL table

Tags: postgresql

How can I extract '2019-06-19 13:30:00-04' from the following SQL table for use in a python file as a variable?

```
SELECT max(begin_ts) FROM ecn_stats_2019_06_19 WHERE name = 'raw_msg_count' and process_name LIKE 'matching_%_gw';

          max
------------------------
 2019-06-19 13:30:00-04
(1 row)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking -- the query you have is returning what sounds like the exact result you want.

Comment: I want to extract the value that I've described for use in a python file as a variable @jmelesky

Comment: You'll want a [python library for postgresql](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/). Once installed, the [basic usage docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) should get you what you need.